# Login utilizando Prepared Statements do MySQLi retorna erro

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estou, pela primeira vez, utilizando *prepared statements*.

Estou confuso e não sei porque não está retornando o usuário autenticado.

Segue meu codigo:

**index.php**

```
<form method="post" action="php/login.php">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
    </div>
  </form>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
require_once "../functions.php";

db_connect();

$sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE username = ?";
$statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
$statement->bind_param('s', $_POST['username']);
$statement->execute();
$statement->store_result();
$statement->bind_result($id, $username, $password);
$statement->fetch();


if ($statement->execute()) {
if(password_verify($_POST['password'], $password)) {
  $_SESSION['user_id'] = $id;
  $_SESSION['user_username'] = $username;
  redirect_to("/home.php");
 } else {
  redirect_to("../index.php?login_error=true");
 }
 } else {
echo "Error: " . $conn->error;
 }
```

**functions.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

function db_connect() {
global $conn; // db connection variable
$db_server = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "xxxxxxxxx";
$db_name = "xxxxxxxxxx";

// create a connection
$conn = new mysqli($db_server, $username, $password, $db_name);

// check connection for errors
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Error: " . $conn->connect_error);

}

}

function redirect_to($url) {
header("Location: " . $url);
exit();
}

function is_auth() {
return isset($_SESSION['user_id']);
}

function check_auth() {
if(!is_auth()) {
  redirect_to("../index.php?logged_in=false");
}
}
```

O erro retornado é:

> *Invalid username or password!*

Que é uma mensagem exibida na página `index.php`.

Comment: Obrigado LipESprY, ele retorna " Invalid username or password! "

Comment: isso mesmo certinho LipESprY index.php?login_error=true

Comment: Adicionei as informações que você passou pelos comentários à sua pergunta. Atente-se a informar, precisamente, esse tipo de informação nas suas próximas perguntas. No mais, pode apagar os seus comentários, como fiz com os meus. Tmj!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe esta parte do seu código:

```
if ($statement->execute()) {
    if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $password)) {
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $id;
        $_SESSION['user_username'] = $username;
        redirect_to("/home.php");
    } else {
        redirect_to("../index.php?login_error=true");
    }
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $conn->error;
}
```

Especificamente nesta linha:

```
if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $password)) {
```

Aqui é feita uma validação, comparando a senha recebia via `$_POST` com a senha armazenada no banco de dados.

Importante considerar o seguinte, conforme [documentação do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.password-verify.php):

> `password_verify` — Verifica se um password corresponde com um hash

Com certeza a senha recebida via método `POST` não corresponde com a senha armazenada no banco de dados.

Mas perceba, com calma:

1. A senha pode estar errada (óbvio);
2. A senha pode estar armazenada de forma "crú";

Quando digo que a senha está "crú", significa que ela não foi armazenada em *hash* gerada pela função [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.password-hash.php).

Por não passar na validação, o usuário (você) é redirecionado para a página `index.php` com os argumentos `login_error=true`. Com certeza sua página `index.php`, após identificar que `login_error` é `true`, exibe essa tal mensagem que você mencionou no comentário.

Comment: Muito obrigado LipESprY, matou na mosca. Verifiquei que a senha havia sido armazenada cru ou seja sem hashear